# dotnet test not filtering on ClassName with SpecFlow tests

Tags: .net, unit-testing, specflow

We're using SpecFlow to generate our tests, and then running them using `dotnet test`. (We can't use the test runner, because we're on OS X and VS2019 for Mac doesn't add the SpecFlow tests to the Unit Tests pad).

I can filter on test name, but cannot filter on test class name.

Given the following generated test class:

```
namespace MyProject.App.Member.SpecTests.Features.Member.Account
{
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute()]
    [NUnit.Framework.DescriptionAttribute("Account Page")]
    public partial class AccountPageFeature
    {
        // Test code here...
    }
}
```

When I run `done test` with the command line:

`dotnet test --framework netcoreapp2.1 --configuration Release --filter ClassName=MyProject.App.Member.SpecTests.Features.Member.Account.AccountPageFeature`

I get the error:

> No test matches the given testcase filter
>   `ClassName=MyProject.App.Member.SpecTests.Features.Member.Account.AccountPageFeature`
>   in
>   /Users/jameslavery/GitHub/MyProject.mobile/test/MyProject.App.Member.SpecTests/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/MyProject.App.Member.SpecTests.dll

Using ClassName is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests). I suspect it's because the generated class hasn't got the `[TestClass]` attribute.

Any pointers on how to get filtering by class working?

Comment: Is specflow configured to use the right testing framework? It uses NUnit by default.

Comment: Yes it is, so that's not the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have the fully qualified class name right? Try just specifying the class name without the namespace.

Comment: you can try like dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~AccountPageFeature"